# Is there any optimisation option that could change the alignment of struct in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-alignment

I've been investigating a weird bug this week. When I compile a third party static library in Release and then link it with my application (in Release also), it crashes with a weird callstack (the this pointer changes even though it's calling a base class functions, and ultimately crash when it tries to access a member). Yesterday, I finally found the root cause of this : the memory layout of the class that I'm using is different in the library than in my application (verified with /d1reportAllClassLayout). It's different in a weird way, i.e. after the base class, there's a 4 + 8 bytes padding in the lib, but in my application, there's a 12 bytes padding. Also, it seems like the base class is a bit shorter, because there's a difference of 16 bytes (IIRC) between the end of the base class and the first member of the sub class. The problem was solved when I force the padding to 8 bytes (/Zp8 option) in my application, which was already done in the library. Only then the class had the same layout in both. Weirder yet, this bug is completely absent when I compile in Debug.

Could a compiler optimization option causes this? Why does setting the /Zp option to 8, which is supposedly the default, changes the layout of the class?

Thanks

Comment: "supposedly"? note: could this be a 32/64bit difference?

Comment: Yes, the MSDN documentation states that the default is /Zp8 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx

Comment: Both the library and my app is in x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, compiler optimizations can definitely change this.  In the interest of making things fast, compilers will typically word-align structs and variables to make moving them around faster (This happens even more often on x64 systems).  This can lead to the types of errors you've seen (where a Struct can change size between Release and Debug, as it internally rearranges the elements to hit word alignment).

You can control this programmatically on sensitive structures using the `__declspec( align( # ) ) declarator` syntax, detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx).  Use that for sensitive data structures and then you can change your code from Debug to Release without the structure changing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't get is why "forcing" the /Zp option to 8 changes the layout, since it's the default option. Do you know any specific optimization that might cause this?

Comment: While I have nothing to prove it, I would suspect that the `/O2`, which includes `/Ot` (documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9534wye.aspx) ) allows the compiler to override the default packing option, if it believes it can do it faster.